# Configure HikariCP in Spring Boot with JTDS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jtds, hikaricp

I want to add a connection pool to my existing web application, which has been made using Spring Boot 1.5.1.

The datasource configuration is made in application.properties as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase;instance=SQLServer2014;
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=passwd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I don't need to make any further configuration, with this is enough.

It isn't clear enough in the official [docs](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), although parameters are shown, nor in the Spring Boot [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database).

So, I've been looking for solutions over there ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250636/configuration-of-jtds-for-use-with-hikaricp-spring-ms-sql-server), [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f)...).

I've made several trials, but everytime I run the app, exceptions regarding HikariCP are thrown.

When adding `spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`, the following exception is thrown:

```
2017-02-15 12:12:23.955  WARN 14844 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
2017-02-15 12:12:23.964  INFO 14844 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-02-15 12:12:23.970 ERROR 14844 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.ingartek.ws.pps.PrestacionesPoliticasSocialesInternoApplication.main(PrestacionesPoliticasSocialesInternoApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:422) ~[HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:393) ~[HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:351) ~[HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:196) ~[HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:442) ~[HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:505) ~[HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:113) ~[HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:97) ~[HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

So, which is the simplest way to add hikaricp to my application.properties?

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml?

Comment: @abaghel is it relevant?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are getting below error.

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)

Issue is that net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection doesn't implement `isValid` so you need to specify a connection-test-query to ensure that `isValid` method isn't called. Try by adding below property in your application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

Comment: I had this problem with spring boot 2.1.5 and using this works!

Comment: Great job!! It works in spring boot 2.5.x

Comment: I appreciate you, I feel calm now

Answer (score 17):

For using multiple datasources (Spring Boot 2.0), I had to do the following to get this to work (setting spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query property only worked when using a single datasource):

```
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource ds = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

        ds.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean(name="secondDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.second")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource ds = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

        ds.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean(name="primaryJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate primaryJdbcTemplate(DataSource primaryDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(primaryDataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name="secondJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate secondJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource secondDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(secondDataSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if this is supposed to work with multiple datasources, in my application this solved the problem with a single datasource ( property spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query didn't worked )

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found the solution from this  [discussion.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7404)
It looks like, before doing any further configurations Hikari CP tests the validity of the connection by executing a test query which is missing in this case.
So as suggested by the earlier answer, you should add one test query in your application.properties file.
If you are using Oracle or mySql then you can use the following query instead (as SELECT 1 doesn't work here):

`spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`

Note: DUAL is a special one-row and one-column table present in Oracle and other databases. Thus it can be readily used to execute a simple test-query.

Comment: Oracle and MySQL do not need a test query, as both drivers implement the isValid() method.

Comment: @brettw if that's the case then why I was also facing the same issue with ojdbc7 10.x? Does it depend on the version of the ojdbc jar then?